# Fill the dates between the dates in same column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Could you please help me?!

I have 2 tables in my desktop(see below) and I want to generate desired table based on the 2 tables I have in Power BI.

| Date | EmpId | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/11/2021 | 100001 | 168 |
| 3/1/2022 | 100001 | 145 |
| 5/5/2022 | 100001 | 160 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100002 | 168 |

Desired Output table should look like below:

| Date | EmpID | EmpName | Contracthours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/2/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/3/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/4/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/5/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/6/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/7/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/8/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/9/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 1/10/2022 | 100001 | Employee A | 168 |
| 2/28/2022 | 10001 | A | 168(till 2/28/2022) |
| 3/1/2022 | 10001 | A | 145(Till 5/4/2022) |

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks. Have a nice day.

I want to fill the dates between the dates in same column in power bi

Comment: Please edit your question to **clarify** and also **show what you have tried**. You write you want to create a third table from two, but you only show one table and the output table. Also, why no dates in output prior to 1/1/2022?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to ask how to repeat the contents of the rows for every date from that row until the date on the row below it, grouping by employee

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"EmpId"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    b = Table.AddColumn(a, "Custom", each try Date.AddDays(a{[Index]+1}[Date],-1) otherwise [Date]),
    c= Table.AddColumn(b, "Custom.1", each {Number.From([Date]) .. Number.From([Custom])}),
    d = Table.ExpandListColumn(c, "Custom.1")
    in d
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Hours", "Custom.1"}, {"Hours", "Custom.1"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Custom.1", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```